# Java converting image to grayscale, image won't show up

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to convert an image into grayscale and output that as another image file, but when I try to run the code, nothing shows up but there's no error message. I'm not sure what is wrong. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GrayScale {
   BufferedImage  image;
   int width;
   int height;
   public GrayScale() {
      try {
         File input = new File("src/image.jpg");
         image = ImageIO.read(input);
         width = image.getWidth();
         height = image.getHeight();
         for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
               Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
               int red = (int)(c.getRed() * 0.2126);
               int green = (int)(c.getGreen() * 0.7152);
               int blue = (int)(c.getBlue() *0.0722);
               Color newColor = new Color(red+green+blue,
               red+green+blue,red+green+blue);
               image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
               }
          }
         File output = new File("grayscale.jpg");
         ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output);
      } catch (Exception e) {}
   }
   static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
   {
      GrayScale obj = new GrayScale();
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? display image path on console or to display image on frame?

Comment: @Prasad I want to display it on the console

Comment: "I'm not sure what is wrong." This is: `catch (Exception e) {}`. :-) Never do this.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working basically. Try inserting

```
try 
{
    File input = new File("src/image.jpg");
    System.out.println("File exists? "+input.exists()); // THIS LINE
    ....
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace(); // AND THIS LINE
}
```

**Never** catch an exception with an empty block in such a case!

---

**EDIT** For showing the image:

```
private static void showImage(final Image image)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This works, but how would I get it so that the image displays on the console? It only prints right now.

Comment: @user3331241 You can't display an image in the console. You can show it in a frame. I added a method `showImage` in my above answer, maybe this is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

The code works. However the newly created image `grayscale.jpg` is not created in the `src` folder where your original image resides (and probably you expect it to be created there), but in the working directory when executed. So e.g. in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write this code after writing output image.

```
System.out.println(output.getAbsolutePath());
```

This will print absolute path of output file on `console`.